# Install Ubuntu 12.04 in Dell Inspiron 1420

Tags: installation, dell, inspiron

I want to install Ubuntu 12.04 on a Dell Inspiron 1420.

Currently that system has Windows Vista installed on it.

After installing Ubuntu, do I need to install all drivers separately?

Answer (score 1):

Installing Ubuntu is usually enough, as it contains the code necessary to run on most hardware. If drivers are required, it will attempt to prompt you via an `Additional Drivers` dialog.

As such, you do not need to install drivers individually.

You can also read a guide on [How to Install Ubuntu 12.04](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/).